# Unable to load JSON file from API into state

Tags: json, reactjs, react-state

After series of code try outs, i'm unable to store a JSON file from an API into state

i've been trying to display the JSON response on the browser console console before fully implementing it. I have this code:

```
//const API;
class WeatherApp extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);


        this.state = {
            location: "",
            reports:[]
        }
    }

//functions should be written outside the constructor method
    onSubmit = event => {
        //prevents default loading of the page when this function "onSubmit"
        //is called
        event.preventDefault();
        //saving the value of the textbox to a variable/const
        if(this.searchbox.value !== ""){ 
            const searchResult = this.searchbox.value;
            //update the state object
            this.setState({
                location: searchResult + " weather report"
            });
        }else{
            alert("please ensure that field is not empty!");
            return;
        }
    };


//${this.searchbox.value + KEY}
componentDidMount(){
    if(this.searchbox.value !== ""){ 
        fetch(`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${this.searchBox.value + KEY} `, {
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON"
        })
        .then( data =>  
            this.setState({ reports: [...this.state.reports, data.list ], })
        );
    }
}


    render(){
        console.log(this.state.reports);

        return(
            <div className="weather-app">
                <WeatherAppHeader />
                <div className="weather-body">
                    <div className="entry-pane">
                        <form onSubmit ={this.onSubmit} >
                            <input 
                                type="text" 
                                id="search-box"
                                placeholder="Location e.g Abuja, NG" 
                                size="40" 
                                ref={input => this.searchbox = input} />

                            <button type="submit" id="search-btn">search</button> 
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <SearchedLocation  location={this.state.location} />
                    <WeatherReport  reports={this.state.reports} />
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

but instead of returning a response containing the JSON object, I get this response. Pls how do i fix this?

```
[ length: 0    __proto__: Array(0)]
```

Comment: This is probably more likely to be a problem with the query you're sending to the API, or a problem with the API itself.

Comment: though i've tried it before but let me try it again in a different way

Comment: what is the format of `KEY`? is its value something like `&APPID=XXXXXXXXX` where the `X` is your actual key?

Comment: @JohnRuddell yes it is

Answer (score 0):

When `fetch` gets an JSON, you need to parse the response object to JSON using [.json](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json)

```
etch(`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${this.searchBox.value + KEY} `, {
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON"
        })
        // ..  ....
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then( data =>  
            this.setState({ reports: [...this.state.reports, data.list ], })
        );
```

Check out some of the `fetch` examples using `response.json()` on MDN.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Do you have any console warnings or error messages?

Comment: no errors at all, just the response as stated in the question above

Comment: what is `dataType` in the fetch request? shouldn't that be a header with `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`?

Comment: dataType is JSON

Comment: @JohnRuddell  Including the contentType still didn't make a difference to the result

Comment: It's not `contentType` what I'm saying is `dataType` isn't a valit param for fetch. You need to pass a headers object with the content type like I specified. `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }` include that in the second param of the fetch request (next to `method`)

Answer (score 0):

In this particular component you aren't actually making the request. You only would do it in `didMount` except that would always be empty, so the fetch would never execute. You should clean up the way this component works.

```
class WeatherApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      location: "",
      reports: []
    };
  }

  //functions should be written outside the constructor method
  onSubmit = event => {
    //prevents default loading of the page when this function "onSubmit"
    //is called
    event.preventDefault();
    //saving the value of the textbox to a variable/const
    if (this.searchbox.value.trim() === "") {
      alert("please ensure that field is not empty!");
      return;
    }
    const searchQuery = this.searchbox.value;
    //update the state object
    this.setState({
      location: searchQuery + " weather report"
    });
    this.searchForReport(searchQuery); 
  };

  searchForReport = searchQuery => {
    fetch(
      `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${searchQuery}&APPID=${KEY}`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
      }
    )
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        // TODO handle bad request here
      }
      response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      const report = data ? data.list : [];
      this.setState({ reports: [...this.state.reports, report] });
    });
  };

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

The point of this would be when you submit the form, you need to actually fetch the data. So you want to do that after validation on the input. I would probably put the value of your input on the component and reference it that way rather than a ref.

Update your `KEY` variable to be just the api key, and pass it as a parameter. Make your code understandable and readable. If the next developer has to go look up a variable to know how the code works that is a dependency that shouldn't be there.

Comment: this didn't work either... i got this message in the console  ``` []length: 0__proto__: Array(0)
localhost/:1 Access to fetch at 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Abuja,NG&appid=e102cc873d6623291973f74bc86a9d13&units=metric' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
index.js:41 GET https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Abuja,NG&appid=e102cc873d6623291973f74bc86a9d13&units=metric net::ERR_FAILED ```